# Delete letter from string in a for loop

Tags: java

How can i get the letter from guess out of alphabet? So if the first guess is AABB i need to get the A and the B out of the String alphabet to make a new random guess without the letters A and B.

```
    randomCode.clear();//Clears the random code ArrayList to put a new one in it
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "ABCDEF";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(randomCode.size());

    if(turn == 0){
        guess = "AABB";

    }else{
        if(blackPin == 0 && whitePin ==0){
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                if(alphabet.charAt(c) == guess.charAt(c)){

                }
                randomCode.add(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));//generate 4 random letters with the letters ABCDEF and put in arrayList
            }
            for (Character c : randomCode){//Converts Char[] randomCode to a String
                result.append(c);
                }
            guess = result.toString();//Gives the String guess 4 random letters.
```

Comment: Iterate over the chars and compare them one by one.
If you use contains, it'll only tell you it's in there, not how many times.

Comment: String in java is immutable so character cannot be deleted in string. For deletion of character use StringBuilder!!!

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times. If it is in there then it shoud be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `ArrayList`, for example:

```
ArrayList<Character> alphabet = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));
```

And a `String`:

```
String guess = "AABB";
```

You can remove from the *alphabet* each letter which occurs in the *guess* as shown:

```
for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++)
    alphabet.remove(new Character(guess.charAt(i)));
```

Now, if print out the *alphabet*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.size(); i++)
    System.out.print(alphabet.get(i));
```

the output will be: `"CD"`.

You can use this all together:

```
ArrayList<Character> alphabet = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));
Random random = new Random();
String guess = "";

while (true) {
    /* init a guess */
    guess = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        guess += alphabet.get(random.nextInt(alphabet.size()));
    System.out.println("The guess is: " + guess);

    /* remove letters */
    for (int j = 0; j < guess.length(); j++)
        alphabet.remove(new Character(guess.charAt(j)));

    /* the alphabet is empty */
    if (alphabet.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("The alphabet is empty");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why loop when you can avoid it:

```
String abd = "ABCDEF";
String guess = "AABB";
System.out.println(abd.replaceAll(String.join("|", guess.split("")), ""));
```

This prints:

CDEF

Comment: From the point of view of the *complexity*, this solution is *O(n)*, just like a `loop` which scan each letter of the input (always *O(n)*).

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way of doing this is to exploit the fact that the ASCII codes of the letters are 26 consecutive integers, and cast from char to int.  Codes 65-68 are ABCD.

http://www.ascii-code.com/